# ¿Cómo extraer una ruta o parte de texto de un archivo xml?

Tags: script, vbscript

Os pongo lo que llevo hecho en los dos primeros puntos:

> 1-      Examinar la ruta que aparece en la clave HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Syncplicity\1.0 RootSyncPointFolder REG_SZ
>
> 2-      Copiar los archivos y carpetas de ésa ruta, conservando la misma estructura a C:\MAGIC_PACKAGE_BETA\Syncplicity

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Syncplicity\1.0" /v RootSyncPointFolder ^| find /i "REG_SZ"') do set SyncFolder=%%a %%b
xcopy  "%SyncFolder%" "C:\MAGIC_PACKAGE_BETA\Syncplicity" /E /I
```

Hasta aquí bien. El problema viene en los puntos 3 y 4 en los que estoy muy perdido. el archivo en el cual tengo que sacar esa información es un .xml

> 3-      Buscar los valores “Path” del archivo %localappdata%\syncplicty\syncpointsState.xml. Nos interesa las rutas que están entrecomilladas.

el valor Path devuelve algo así: `Path="C:\DATA\DRIVER_M910Q_USB_3_0"` Siempre devuelve una ruta.

Hay que buscar (espacio Path igual)

> 4-      Sacar un mensaje en el que aparezcan todas las rutas encontradas en el punto 3. El usuario debe aceptar éste mensaje para que el paquete continúe. Ésas rutas también deben de guardarse en un archivo Additionalfolders.log dentro de C:\MAGIC_PACKAGE_BETA\Syncplicity. Ésta ruta y el archivo deben de aparecer en el mensaje.

Si pongo la siguiente linea, donde "prueba.txt" contiene el contenido del archivo.xml en cuestión, me saca todo el contenido del archivo. no solo lo que yo quiero.

type prueba.txt | findstr " Path="

Answer (score 1):

Supongo por el codigo que hablas de Batch de wondows y no de VBScript. 
Si es asi, para el comando del `for` te aconsejo `FIND " Path=" "%localappdata%\syncplicty\syncpointsState.xml"`, eso deberia funcionar, sinó que leas [Esto](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) sobre el manejo de substring (que incluye la forma de encontrar una string dentro de otra) y quizas [esto](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) pueda ayudarte en tu bucle de lectura. Te pongo un ejemplo no muy correcto:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('type %localappdata%\syncplicty\syncpointsState.xml') do ( SET SyncFolder=%%A && CALL :Comprobar )
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
:Comprobar
    SET SyncFolder=%SyncFolder:"=%
    IF NOT "%SyncFolder:Path=%"=="%SyncFolder%" (
        ECHO "%SyncFolder:~5%"
    )
GOTO :EOF
```